# Repainting line serie with updated data on scale change

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have a line serie, let's call it *duration*. Duration should render at the bottom om the chart, whatever the bottom is based on 15 other line series in the chart. So basically I'm only really interested in the x-value of *duration*.

My idea is to update the y values of the data serie for *duration* whenever the scale changes. Find the minimum scale value and use that as y-value in the serie.

Se the red line in the image:
[image]

However, I can not get this to work. Whenever I update the line series in the eventhandler for `onScaleChange` the data gets updated but the line does not render, or re-render.

Here's a simplification of how I've implemented the event. Assuming there are already a couple of line series with y-values between 300 and 600 I expect the durationSerie to ultimately render at y=300

```
const durationData = [{x: 17, y: 0}, {x: 18, y: 0}]
const durationSerie = lightningChart
  .addLineSeries()
  .add(durationData);

axisY.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
  const newData = durationData.map(data => ({x: data.x, y: start}));
  durationSerie
     .clear()
     .add(newData);
}
```

The line renders at y=0 until `onScaleChange` is run. Then it disappears (because I run the `clear()`command). The `durationSerie` still reports minY and maxY correctly when logged (it report the value corresponding to `start`).

I have tried to run other commands on the `durationSerie`, like setting a new stroke color. That all works fine as long as I do not run the `clear()` command, and of course the line is still displayed at y=0.

Is there another event I need to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this with latest version `@arction/lcjs@4.0.2` and seemed to work as expected. Here's the migrated code:

```
const durationData = [{x: 17, y: 0}, {x: 18, y: 0}]
const durationSerie = lightningChart().ChartXY()
  .addLineSeries()
  .add(durationData);

durationSerie.axisY.onIntervalChange((_, start, end) => {
  const newData = durationData.map(data => ({x: data.x, y: start}));
  durationSerie
     .clear()
     .add(newData);
})
```

You can paste it into one of our online examples to test it https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0017-largeLineChartXY.html

Not sure what is actually causing issue on your end.

Comment: Perhaps version. I'm running 3.4.0